# How to duplicate a button on this page, to be beside it

Tags: php, html, css

I have a site and this is a button on it:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjtJ.png)

I want the exact same button, right beside it, and recenter the buttons.

This is the code for it:

```
<div class="relative ">
        <!-- Slider -->
        <div class="swiper  !py-1" style="max-width: 250px;">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <article>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="joinDiscord()" class="dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:border-jacarta-700 border-jacarta-100 block rounded-[1.25rem] border bg-white p-[1.1875rem] transition-shadow hover:shadow-lg ">
                  <figure>
                    <img src="./img/discord.png" alt="item 1" width="100" height="100" class="w-full rounded-[0.625rem]" loading="lazy" />
                  </figure>
                  <div class="mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                    <span class="font-display text-jacarta-700 hover:text-accent text-base dark:text-white">Join us
                      on discord </span>
                    <span class="dark:border-jacarta-600 border-jacarta-100 flex items-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md border py-1 px-2">
                      <span data-tippy-content="Gems">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-gem" viewBox="0 0 22 16">
                          <path d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495 8 13.366l2.532-7.876-5.062.005zm-1.371-.999-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l5.113 6.817-2.192-6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817 5.123-6.83-2.928.002-2.195 6.828z" />
                        </svg>
                      </span>
                      <span class="text-green text-sm font-medium tracking-tight">+<?php echo getCodes()["RewardYFWz"]["Reward"]; ?></span>
                    </span>
                  </div>


                  <div class="mt-8 flex items-center justify-between">


                    <div class="flex items-center space-x-1">


                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </article>
            </div>
```

I tried adding this:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <article>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="joinDiscord()" class="dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:border-jacarta-700 border-jacarta-100 block rounded-[1.25rem] border bg-white p-[1.1875rem] transition-shadow hover:shadow-lg ">
            <figure>
                <img src="./img/discord.png" alt="item 1" width="100" height="100" class="w-full rounded-[0.625rem]" loading="lazy" />
            </figure>
            <div class="mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                <span class="font-display text-jacarta-700 hover:text-accent text-base dark:text-white">Join us on discord </span>
                <span class="dark:border-jacarta-600 border-jacarta-100 flex items-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md border py-1 px-2">
                    <span data-tippy-content="Gems">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-gem" viewBox="0 0 22 16">
                            <path d="M3.1.7a.5.5 0 0 1 .4-.2h9a.5.5 0 0 1 .4.2l2.976 3.974c.149.185.156.45.01.644L8.4 15.3a.5.5 0 0 1-.8 0L.1 5.3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.6l3-4zm11.386 3.785-1.806-2.41-.776 2.413 2.582-.003zm-3.633.004.961-2.989H4.186l.963 2.995 5.704-.006zM5.47 5.495 8 13.366l2.532-7.876-5.062.005zm-1.371-.999-.78-2.422-1.818 2.425 2.598-.003zM1.499 5.5l5.113 6.817-2.192-6.82L1.5 5.5zm7.889 6.817 5.123-6.83-2.928.002-2.195 6.828z" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text-green text-sm font-medium tracking-tight">+<?php echo getCodes()["RewardYFWz"]["Reward"]; ?></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-8 flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-1">
                    <button type="button" onclick="joinDiscord()" class="bg-jacarta-700 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-accent transition-colors duration-300">Join now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>
</div>
```

but it put the button below the other button, and it kind of merged them together, the distance was not correct either.

Comment: It's more like CSS/HTML than PHP problem.

Comment: my bad, I edited the tags accordingly

Comment: Just copy the entire code block of your button, embed both divs in an other div, and `display: flex`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though, where do I put the display: flex?